# Disable confirmation popup in Dynamics 365 when record is deactivated

Tags: javascript, popupwindow, dynamics-365, clientscript

When one deactivates a record Dynamics 365 is showing a confirmation popup.

[image]

Is there any chance to prevent this confirmation to popup? I've done quite alot of research but was no able to find any reasonable way of disabling this popup.

Does anybody have an idea?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go is hide the original Deactive button and replace it with a custom one performing basically the same action.